# Should js and php objects be treated as different objects in an interaction diagram?

Tags: javascript, php, uml, domain-driven-design, sequence-diagram

I'm drawing a communication diagram for an application where you can buy books. I'm using domain driven design and have a 'shop' object, a 'cart' object, a 'book' object.

My **first communication diagram**, for when the user first comes to the site, is **straight forward**. I generate all html (to show all books and an empty cart) back end with the help of php. I use an MVC pattern; so first I send a message to a 'controller' which creates a 'shop' with 'book's and an empty 'cart' before sending these to the view.

My **second communication diagram** is where I run into **problem**: It is about adding a book from the shop to the cart. I already have all the information I need to add the book to the 'cart' on the client side; since all book information is already in the shop. So when writing the communication diagram, should my first message, i.e. AddBookToCart(bookId:int), be to a JavaScript object called 'shop' which gets the book info and send a message 'AddBookToCart(bookinfo:object) to 'cart' which in turn update the page?

I have never done communication diagrams with JavaScript in mind before so I'm really confused about how to deal with the front end.

(I have been searching for over 5 hours but find nothing on this topic. It's like it's not even an issue to people. Am I viewing this problem completely wrong? Otherwise any resources, or even search terms to use to learn about how to model (and code) these kind of things would be much appreciated)

Comment: I wouldn't bring language into it, but I would bring the logical 'layer' into it if it adds value.  So 'front-end', 'domain', 'bus', and so on, and represent that however one would on a communication diagram.  Don't know if that helps :)

Comment: In future, please do not cross-post questions. For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Since you have received answers to your question posted on the other site, I'm going to closethis one (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223980/should-javascript-and-php-objects-be-treated-as-different-objects-in-an-interact).

Answer (score 1):

In UML there are strict diagrams, as Classes, Packages, Data; and non-strict ones. A communication diagram belong to the last. You can set your own rules about what and how to show there. Any advice would be of the style type.

I would first create the component diagram, to divide different levels of architecture, and only after that turn to communication diagrams. If you would need help again, please, publish here the appropriate component diagram for us to understand what you are talking about.